How to integrate Spring Security with Spring MVC?
I am new to Spring and I try to make users login in before accessing specific endpoint. I am following "Spring MVC Beginner's Guide. Your ultimate guide to building a complete web application using all the capabilities of Spring MVC" but code presented there ddin't work for me. I am getting a following error which I can't solve (I post only first and last line of stack trace because it's quite long):
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.packt</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstore</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>webstore</finalName>
    </build>

</project>

web.xml:
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/ WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

security-context.xml:
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/products/add" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        <security:form-login
                login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/products/add"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
                always-use-default-target="true"
        />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout"/>
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="Admin" password="{noop}Admin123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


I've tried modyfing web.xml and after removing springSecurityFilterChain application was built but logging didn't work properly. Also tried to remove <context-param> and set security-context.xml location in servlet's contextConfigLocation. As I have no experience with Spring I have no idea how to fix this problem. Please help me.

That book seems to be 10 years old and therefore out of date. It is very unlikely that you will be successful simply upgrading to the latest version and following that book as a tutorial. I recommend checking out Spring Security Samples and more recent books or tutorials.

the book you are following is from 2014 thats 10 years ago, the information there is not relevant anymore, and the book does not use spring version 6. Please find a different resource.
